# android DateUtils showing future time after convert timestamp to time ago

Tags: php, android, datetime

I am trying to convert timestamp to time ago format, i am getting future time like in 5 hours instead of 1 min ago. My timestamp `1500030220000`. below id my code.

```
 CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(eventlist.gettimestamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        holder.timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
```

in my PHP i am using strtotime to convert datetime to timestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$timestamp = strtotime($row["date"])*1000;
```

when i check the date and time in timestamp converter [website](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

its giving accurate result. but in my app its showing in 5 hours. do need to set any timezone in app ?

Comment: Your server time is GMT so whenever the time get from the server you need to add your local GMT time.

Comment: where i need to do it in PHP or in android

Comment: Do it in android side.

Comment: In android. You can not do it on PHP because it connect with server and server time is idle in GMT which access by glob level. So whenever you get the time you need to add or deduct the local GMT from the actual time you get.

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018647/5908465]

Comment: Andy can you help me, how to do that

Comment: Thank you i added timezone its working prefect

Answer (score 0):

if anybody looking for the same solution. below is my code

```
int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();

        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(eventlist.gettimestamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis()+gmtOffset, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        holder.timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
```

adding `getRawoffset();` its working perfetc