# Auto-updating time for chatting

Tags: java, android, time

How can we get time?

For instance:

1 min ago
1 sec ago
today
yesterday
tuesday

before 7 days (1 week ago) it must show the date.

Comment: Similar questions were already asked here multiple times, please use search before asking...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Time Since/Ago" Library for Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018550/time-since-ago-library-for-android-java)

Comment: Thanks to all  your revert, but I need to implement multiple functionality once time, so I get only ago method in searching here, and  not showing hour ago or date together in one method that's why, i need to ask this question here ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar thing using the DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString().

It will return at date once it's > 1 week

```
public String timeSinceNow(Date date) {
    long test = date.getTime();
    String result = "";

    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long milliseconds = (millis - test);
    long minutes = 0;
    long hours = 0;
    long days = 0;

    days = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hours = (int) ((milliseconds - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    minutes = (int) (milliseconds - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * hours)) / (1000 * 60);

    if (days > 0 || hours > 0 || minutes > 0) {
        if (hours > 0) {
            if (minutes > 0) {
                if (days == 0) {
                    if (hours == 0) {
                        if (minutes < 3) {
                            result = "Now";
                        } else {
                            result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(test, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(test, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
                    }
                }
                else{
                        result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(test, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
                    }

            }else{
                result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(test, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
            }
        }else{
            result = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(test, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
        }
    } else {
        result = "Now";
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will return a String with the difference between "Now" and the date you pass as a parameter

Comment: Thanks so much sir

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

If your'e saving the date, you can just use Period:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(1978, 3, 26, 12, 35, 0, 0);
DateTime now = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(myDate, now);

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds ago\n")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes ago\n")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours ago\n")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days ago\n")
    .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks ago\n")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months ago\n")
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years ago\n")
    .printZeroNever()
    .toFormatter();

String elapsed = formatter.print(period);
System.out.println(elapsed);
```

Prints:

```
3 seconds ago
51 minutes ago
7 hours ago
6 days ago
10 months ago
31 years ago
```

[From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time)